# ES error no [query] registered for [filtered]

Tags: elasticsearch

I use ES 6.3.5 When I make a POST to get some data it fails
here is my payload, it was used on the past with an older version of Elasticsearch and worked just fine. Am I doing something wrong?

```
{
    "size": 100,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "query": {
                                "match": {
                                    "component": {
                                        "query": "machine1.usermanager",
                                        "type": "phrase"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "fields": [
        "@timestamp",
        "component",
        "logger",
        "level",
        "message",
        "stack_trace"
    ],
    "sort": {
        "@timestamp": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filtered query has been removed.
You can use now a bool query with a filter clause.